How to populate the username in OKTA form using SAML
I want to populate the username in the Okta login form using SAML.
So far I found out that it can be achieved using Subject tag, but I did not manage to make it work. Has anyone done it and can give me some steps to follow?
I tried adding the Subject tag in the createAuthnRequest method from OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestFactory, but looks like okta ignores it

I don't think you'll be able to do that. I suppose that you are trying to send SAML AuthN request from your app to Okta, which is an IdP for you.

Yes, OKTA is my IdP. I know that using OIDC integration you can achieve this by sending the username in login_hint parameter. For SAML  integration all I could find is that this might be achieved using the Subject tag, but there is no final answer. Some people said you can, other said you can't...
